# Solving $ a^x=x $

Tags: calculus

If $a^x=x$ has only one solution in $x$ for $a>1$, determine the value of $a$ and $x$ .

This is to determine the single meeting point of the curves $y=x$ and $y=a^x$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $x=a^x$ has only one solution, then $y=x$ is tangent to $y=a^x$.

$ \implies \frac{dy}{dx}=a^x \ln a$.

Since, it has slope 1 at some $(x_1,y_1)$,

$\implies a^x \ln a=1 \quad -(1)$

But, $a^x=x$

$\implies a=e^{\frac {1}{x}} \quad -(2)$

Putting $(2)$ in $(1)$ gives,

$\implies x=e$

$\implies a=e^{\frac{1}{e}}$

Comment: Sorry, I've not seen the $a>1$ condition first.

Comment: Good answer, just note to the future, when you have 2 functions don't call both with the same name, when you say $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=a^x\ln a\implies a^x\ln a=1$ can be confusing. Better way will be to say $y=a^x,f=x$ and then $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{df}{dx}\implies a^x\ln a=1$. But nonetheless great answer